# Sklearn Linear Regression with Cross Validate Returns NA Accuracy Scores

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, cross-validation

I am running a very simple initial Linear Regression model with basic inputs. I have a small dataset and have removed all nulls. I use cross validate and pass the scoring methods in order to be able to retrieve the scores to judge under/overfitting.

However, I get a Null Accuracy: does anyone know why this would happen?

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, random_state=42)

#Linear Regression

lr = linear_model.LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True)

scores_lr = cross_validate(lr, X_train, y_train, return_train_score = True, scoring = ('r2', 'neg_mean_squared_error'), cv=10)

print 'Training Accuracy: ', np.sqrt(-scores_lr['train_r2'].mean())
print 'Training RMSE: ', np.sqrt(-scores_lr['train_neg_mean_squared_error'].mean())
print 'Validation Accuracy: ', np.sqrt(-scores_lr['test_r2'].mean())
print 'Validation RMSE: ', np.sqrt(-scores_lr['test_neg_mean_squared_error'].mean()) 

Training Accuracy:  nan
Training RMSE:  1.0170113520623867
Validation Accuracy:  nan
Validation RMSE:  1.0230034705533613
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be taking the sqrt of a negative number, resulting in an nan. What measure are you trying to compute? Accuracy is usually used in classification problems. It is defined as the proportion of the correctly predicted classes out of the total number of observations. Since you are using a linear regression model and also compute the Root Mean Squared Error your area of application seems to be regression (working with continous values). The R2 measure which you try to take the sqrt of is the fraction of variance which your current model is able to explain (speaking in general terms). It should need no further processing.